# structs, typedefs, and c header files; how to integrate without .c file

Tags: c, file, struct

I have a project where I need a ton on structs, and as an example, I will use this codebyte (not from project)

```
  typedef struct THING{
        int a;
        int b;
        float stuff;
    } THING;
```

The question I have is can I have a header file containing these typedefs and structs (i.e. structures.h) WITHOUT a related code file (structures.c)? Or what would be the proper method to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can have a header without a c file of the same name

Comment: You need to understand that the header files are simply chunks of code *included* in the `c` files with corresponding directive.

Comment: If you had a structures.c, what would you put in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hard rule that a header file with a given name has to have a corresponding source file of the same name.

If your header only has struct type definitions and typedefs then there's no need for there to be a corresponding .c file.  If the file had function or global variable declarations then they would need to be defined in a .c file somewhere, however that file doesn't have to have the same name as the .h file.

Comment: While there is none in the language, there is often one in the code styles adopted by different entities - with assumption that every header file needs a unit test file to it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I appreciate it. Whenever stack lets me mark your answer as the answer, I will (its saying 9 minutes)

Comment: Be careful.  "struct definitions" is a misleading term here.  It is rarely, if ever, appropriate to have definitions of struct objects in a header, but of course, that's not what the OP presents.  His are definitions of *types*.